# DebugKit Error: CakePHP get() mystery empty elements in associations

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

**EDIT: This is after upgrading from CakePHP 4.0 to 4.3**

With DebugKit turned on, CakePHP is throwing the following error message:

```
Argument 1 passed to Cake\ORM\Entity::get() must be of the type string, bool given, called in /Users/thomasbelknap/one-vision/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Datasource/EntityTrait.php on line 607
```

This appears to be as a result of an empty, numerically-indexed element in the return array of a database query. Let me explain:

In my system, a User has many Estimates (and also Carts and Orders, but more on that). These two clauses in the User and Estimate table files bare this out:

```php
$this->belongsTo('Users', [
   'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
]);
::snip::
$this->hasMany('Estimates', [
   'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
   'dependent' => true,
]);
```

I am querying this information on a "Dashboard" page using the following query structure:

```php
$user = $this->Users->get($this->getRequest()->getSession()->read('Auth.id'), [
    'contain' => [
        'UserGroups',
        'Carts' => function ($q) {
            return $q->limit(5);
        },
        'Orders' => function ($q) {
            return $q->limit(5);
        },
        'Orders.OrderStatuses',
        'Estimates' => function ($q) {
            return $q->limit(5);
        },
        'Estimates.EstimateStatuses',
    ],
]);
```

I am not doing any further transformation of the data. There are no Collection functions being employed here. Nevertheless, in the estimates returned, there is always a mystery, numerically-indexed and empty array element:

```
[1] => Visualize\Model\Entity\Estimate Object
(
    [id] => 30
    [user_id] => 1
    [estimate_status_id] => 5
    [estimate_po] => lksjdf
    [estimate_total] => 
    [name] => Full throttle
    [instore_date] => Cake\I18n\FrozenDate Object
        (
            [date] => 2022-12-31 00:00:00.000000
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => EST
        )

    [notes] => Let's do this. 
    [created] => Cake\I18n\FrozenTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2022-04-19 13:20:39.000000
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => EST
        )

    [modified] => Cake\I18n\FrozenTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2022-04-19 13:21:26.000000
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => EST
        )

    [1] => 
    [location_info] => Array
        (
        )

    [[new]] => 
    [[accessible]] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 1
            [estimate_status_id] => 1
            [estimate_po] => 1
            [estimate_total] => 1
            [name] => 1
            [instore_date] => 1
            [notes] => 1
            [created] => 1
            [modified] => 1
            [user] => 1
            [line_items] => 1
            [orders] => 1
            [estimate_options] => 1
        )

    [[dirty]] => Array
        (
        )

    [[original]] => Array
        (
        )

    [[virtual]] => Array
        (
            [item_count] => 1
            [box_count] => 1
            [deliverable_count] => 1
            [0] => location_info
            [estimate_total] => 1
        )

    [[hasErrors]] => 
    [[errors]] => Array
        (
        )

    [[invalid]] => Array
        (
        )

    [[repository]] => Estimates
)
```

This **only affects the Estimates part of the query!** The other two elements do not have this mystery index. Here's what CakePHP ultimately uses as it's query, which again, seems fine:

```sql
SELECT 
  Estimates.id AS Estimates__id, 
  Estimates.user_id AS Estimates__user_id, 
  Estimates.estimate_status_id AS Estimates__estimate_status_id, 
  Estimates.estimate_po AS Estimates__estimate_po, 
  Estimates.estimate_total AS Estimates__estimate_total, 
  Estimates.name AS Estimates__name, 
  Estimates.instore_date AS Estimates__instore_date, 
  Estimates.notes AS Estimates__notes, 
  Estimates.created AS Estimates__created, 
  Estimates.modified AS Estimates__modified, 
  EstimateStatuses.id AS EstimateStatuses__id, 
  EstimateStatuses.name AS EstimateStatuses__name, 
  EstimateStatuses.description AS EstimateStatuses__description, 
  EstimateStatuses.created AS EstimateStatuses__created, 
  EstimateStatuses.modified AS EstimateStatuses__modified 
FROM 
  estimates Estimates 
  LEFT JOIN estimate_statuses EstimateStatuses ON EstimateStatuses.id = Estimates.estimate_status_id 
WHERE 
  Estimates.user_id in (1) 
ORDER BY 
  Estimates.modified DESC 
LIMIT 
  5
```

For obvious reasons, I really need the DebugKit to work, but I have no idea where this mystery element is coming from. Everything seems right, to me?

**Edit: Adding the definition of my estimate entity:**

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Visualize\Model\Entity;

use Cake\ORM\Entity;

/**
 * Estimate Entity
 *
 * @property int $id
 * @property int $user_id
 * @property int|null $estimate_status_id
 * @property string|null $estimate_po
 * @property float|null $estimate_total
 * @property string $name
 * @property \Cake\I18n\FrozenDate $instore_date
 * @property string $notes
 * @property \Cake\I18n\FrozenTime $created
 * @property \Cake\I18n\FrozenTime $modified
 *
 * @property \Visualize\Model\Entity\User $user
 * @property \Visualize\Model\Entity\LineItem[] $line_items
 * @property \Visualize\Model\Entity\Order[] $orders
 * @property \Visualize\Model\Entity\EstimateOption[] $estimate_options
 * @property float $item_count
 * @property int $box_count
 * @property array|\Cake\Collection\CollectionInterface|null $by_location
 * @property int $deliverable_count
 * @property array $location_info
 * @property \Visualize\Model\Entity\EstimateStatus|null $estimate_status
 * @property array|\Cake\Collection\CollectionInterface|null $by_deliverable
 */
class Estimate extends Entity
{
    /**
     * Fields that can be mass assigned using newEntity() or patchEntity().
     *
     * Note that when '*' is set to true, this allows all unspecified fields to
     * be mass assigned. For security purposes, it is advised to set '*' to false
     * (or remove it), and explicitly make individual fields accessible as needed.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_accessible = [
        'user_id' => true,
        'estimate_status_id' => true,
        'estimate_po' => true,
        'estimate_total' => true,
        'name' => true,
        'instore_date' => true,
        'notes' => true,
        'created' => true,
        'modified' => true,
        'user' => true,
        'line_items' => true,
        'orders' => true,
        'estimate_options' => true,
    ];

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_virtual = [
        'item_count' => true,
        'box_count' => true,
        'deliverable_count' => true,
        'location_info' => true,
        'estimate_total' => true,
    ];

    /**
     * Returns a zero-filled version of the cannonical ID
     *
     * @param int $id The autoincremental ID
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getId($id): string
    {
        return sprintf('%05d', $id);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the sum of quantities of all line items.
     *
     * @return float
     */
    protected function _getItemCount(): float
    {
        $count = 0;
        if (!empty($this->line_items)) {
            $collection = new \Cake\Collection\Collection($this->line_items);
            $count = $collection->sumOf('quantity');
        }

        return (float)$count;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the count of locations in the estimate
     *
     * @return int
     */
    protected function _getBoxCount(): int
    {
        $count = 0;
        if (!empty($this->line_items)) {
            $collection = new \Cake\Collection\Collection($this->line_items);
            $collection = $collection->combine('location_id', 'id');
            $count = $collection->count();
        }

        return $count;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the total number of deliverable types in the order.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    protected function _getDeliverableCount(): int
    {
        $count = 0;
        if (!empty($this->line_items)) {
            $collection = new \Cake\Collection\Collection($this->line_items);
            $collection = $collection->combine('deliverable_id', 'id');
            $count = $collection->count();
        }

        return $count;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the list of locations for this estimate
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function _getLocationInfo(): array
    {
        $info = [];
        if (!empty($this->line_items)) {
            $collection = new \Cake\Collection\Collection($this->line_items);
            $info = $collection->combine(
                'location_id',
                function ($entity) {
                    return $entity->location;
                }
            );

            return $info->toArray();
        }

        return $info;
    }


    /**
     * Returns either the name or the id of the given estimate
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getName(): string
    {
        return $this->name ?? (string)$this->id;
    }

    public const FIELD_ID = 'id';
    public const FIELD_USER_ID = 'user_id';
    public const FIELD_ESTIMATE_STATUS_ID = 'estimate_status_id';
    public const FIELD_ESTIMATE_PO = 'estimate_po';
    public const FIELD_ESTIMATE_TOTAL = 'estimate_total';
    public const FIELD_NAME = 'name';
    public const FIELD_INSTORE_DATE = 'instore_date';
    public const FIELD_NOTES = 'notes';
    public const FIELD_CREATED = 'created';
    public const FIELD_MODIFIED = 'modified';
    public const FIELD_USER = 'user';
    public const FIELD_LINE_ITEMS = 'line_items';
    public const FIELD_ORDERS = 'orders';
    public const FIELD_ESTIMATE_OPTIONS = 'estimate_options';
    public const FIELD_ITEM_COUNT = 'item_count';
    public const FIELD_BOX_COUNT = 'box_count';
    public const FIELD_BY_LOCATION = 'by_location';
    public const FIELD_DELIVERABLE_COUNT = 'deliverable_count';
    public const FIELD_LOCATION_INFO = 'location_info';
    public const FIELD_ESTIMATE_STATUS = 'estimate_status';
    public const FIELD_BY_DELIVERABLE = 'by_deliverable';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a close look at the dump of the entity, that field is apparently configured as an [**exposed virtual field**](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/entities.html#exposing-virtual-fields), and looking at the other exposed fields, they seem to be configured incorrectly, as that property should hold a flat array of strings, not string indexed entries like `'item_count' => 1`, as the value declares the field name, hence why you see a field named `1`.

You are also misinterpreting the output, `location_info` does not belong to the `1` field, that's actually two different fields, `1` which holds something empty-ish that PHP doesn't print, like `null` or `false`, and `location_info` which holds an empty array.

Use `debug()` instead of `pr()/print_r()` to get a better structured dump which also properly shows empty data. And then inspect your `Estimate` entity class (or wherever things may be configured on the fly) and fix up the virtual fields.

Comment: I neglected to mention that I upgraded from CakePHP4.0 to 4.3. I have further discovered that, if I leave the $_virtual array empty, the '1' index is gone. But with any virtual fields at all, I get the index back?

Comment: Huh! Sorry, for some reason, my $_virtual was not formatted correctly, exactly as you said. Thank you kindly as always, @ndm!